# How to show button after typing text in textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my table crated dynamically. Also I created textbox that should disable all other text boxes after user click to input text in one of them. What I'm struggling is to get button created just next to text box which I clicked on. My current code show the button on the same spot. Does not matter which text box I clicked on my button always show up next to the first text box. 
HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td>#TimeFormat(StartTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
    <td>#TimeFormat(EndTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
        <input type="button" id="test" name="test" value="Save" onClick="testButton()" style="display: none">
   </td>
</tr>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":text").keyup(function(e) {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $(":text").not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            $("#test").show();
        } else {
            $(":text").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#test").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why button show up only in the first row. My text box function works fine. If I click in one text box all other will be blocked. Only issue is that my button is not created next to the text box that I clicked but first one. If anyone see where is my code breaking please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because all of the buttons have the same id. So, `$("#test")` always finds the first button:

You need to use a class instead of id, like this:

```
<input type="button" class="test" value="Save" onClick="testButton()" style="display: none">
```

Then, your key-up event should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":text").keyup(function(e) {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $(":text").not(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            $(this).next(".test").show();
        } else {
            $(":text").removeAttr('disabled');
            $(this).next(".test").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you know why I can not get values from other text boxes but first one? I try to do this: var test2 = $('.test').val();
  alert(test2);

Comment: Of course. Because,  `$(':text')` selects everything that's a text input. It's similar to your first problem.

Comment: Should I use class instead of $(':test')?

Comment: They all have the same id of 'fname'. You need to give them a class, and then use `$(this).prev(".fname")` (assuming the class is `fname`).

Comment: Submit a new question, if you still have any problem.

Comment: I did not understand your answer, I'm trying to pass values from the input to onClick function. I use $('.fname').val(); and that gives me just value for the first text box.

Comment: I didn't say you should use `$('.fname').val();`. My comment is right above. Use `$(this).prev(".fname").val();`. But, again, you need to ask a new question.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what to do, unless I see your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `next()` and `prev()` to find next and previous element like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
$(".fname").keyup(function (e) {
     if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(".fname").not(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).next(".test").show();
     } else {
        $(".fname").removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).next(".test").hide();
     }
});

$(".test").click(function (e) {
     alert($(this).prev(".fname").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>#TimeFormat(StartTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
        <td>#TimeFormat(EndTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="fname">
            <input type="button" class="test" name="test" value="Save" style="display: none">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>#TimeFormat(StartTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
        <td>#TimeFormat(EndTime,'hh:mm tt')#</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="fname">
            <input type="button" class="test" name="test" value="Save" style="display: none">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update:**

**Button:**

```
<input type="button" class="test" name="test" 
     onclick="testButton(this)" value="Save" style="display: none">
```

**JS Function**

```
function testButton(btn) {
    var test = $(btn).prev('.fname').val();
    alert(test);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that solved this problem. Another thing what does not work now is if I enter text and click on button I'm getting value just for the first input field, if I enter text in any other input field and click on button I will get empty alert. What can cause this problem?

Comment: This is not a good answer. You shouldn't use the same id for all the buttons on the page.

Comment: See the updated answer. Hope this will solve your problem. @user3023588

Comment: What if I want to pass value in javascript function like this: function testButton(){
  var test = $('.fname').prev('.fname').val();
  alert(test);
 } this code gives me undefined value in alert box.?

Comment: I tried this too:var test = document.getElementsByClassName('fname').value;

Comment: Thank you, that works. Can you explain why I have to use .prev() to get all values? I would like to understand this.

Comment: Because every `textbox` is placed before it's corresponding `button` and there are multiple `textbox` and `button` pair. So to find only the previous `textbox` of the `button` you have to use `prev()` @user3023588

Comment: How I can do email validation of my input field type="text"? I tried to use JQuery validation email but is not that good. First time if I enter wrong email that form works fine but If I click twice on the button my email will be submitted even if it's wrong formatted. Is there any other way to check email before submitting?

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Azim is partially correct, the "next" selector can't be an ID selector, otherwise you select only the specific textbox with the specific ID.
The right way is:

```
$(this).next("input").show();
```

Example: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ycbth9qz/)